# random.Next(0,7) ArgumentOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to add a dice command to my discord bot
It works perfectly if I do not specify the range -> rand.Next()
However, when I add a range (1,7), it keeps showing "Exception: ArgumentOutOfRangeException"

```
      commands.CreateCommand("dice")
           .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int num = rand.Next(1,7); 
                string s = Convert.ToString(num);
                await e.Channel.SendMessage(s);
            });
```

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgLl6.jpg

edit: (1,7) instead of (0,7)

Comment: I think it should be `Next(1,7)` because dice cannot have 0

Comment: True, my fault, but the main error is still up there, thanks :)

Comment: Are you _actually_ getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or are you just reading the Visual Studio tooltip?

Comment: Reading the tooltip, but it doesn't work anyway :/, and like I said, when the range it's not specified, this ArgumentOutOfRangeException doesn't appear and works perfectly

Comment: what happens if you replace `int num = rand.Next(1,7);` with `int num = 6;` in your code? no error? (Also check `int num = 0;` )

Comment: I really think that you are just reading the tooltip. If you have `Random.Next()` without range and you read the tooltip, you won't see any Exception info because that overload doesn't throw exceptions. When you specify a range, _that_ overload throws exception when `min` > `max`

Comment: No error, it just returns 6 or 0

Comment: When I write on the Discord chat "!dice" when it's Next(1,7), it doesn't return anything, but if I do the same when it's Next() it return a random number

Comment: Then there is something else wrong. Have a look at your `e.Channel.SendMessage(s)`.  Can you post that code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BBaZar64

Comment: Need the `e.Channel.SendMessage(s)` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your arguments or your syntax. I check it like five times lol.

How about try putting the Random rand = new Random();
out of the function (I'm guessing the async setting is the one causing the problem) or better yet generate the random number outside async if possible.

Comment: Oh wow, your Error is quite weird. If I were you my next step would be debugging. Like follow the code or something. 

Lastly have you tried doing, "rand.Next(6)" since this will result to 0-5 just put ++ on num when you are converting it to string

Comment: Wow, I'm 100% sure I've done it before. It suddenly started working!! Weirdly, the "Exception" is still there. Anyways, thanks for that "miracle" :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that rand.Next(1,7) is throwing exceptions? It checks for *minValue>maxValue*

```
if (minValue>maxValue) {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minValue",Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_MinMaxValue", "minValue", "maxValue"));
  }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

You can try to delete bin/obj folders and rebuild your whole solution